# sobre react y setsate

Tags: reactstrap

Hola master esto lo entiendo bien

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      personas: [
        { id: 1, nombre: "Adolfo" },
        { id: 2, nombre: "Juan" }
      ]
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    let personas = this.state.personas
    personas.forEach(item => {
      if (item.id === 2) item.nombre = "Jose"
      return item
    })
    this.setState({ personas })
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.personas)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <div className="App-intro">
          { 
            this.state.personas 
            ? this.state.personas.map((item, index) => {
              return <p key={index}>
                {this.state.personas[index].id} - {this.state.personas[index].nombre}
              </p>         
            })
            : ''
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

PREGUNTA: LO QUIERO HACER DESDE UNA FUNCION PROPIA Y CON UNA SOLA PROPIEDAD Y NO ME SALE Y ME TRAVE DE ESTA MANERA

```
 ver(e){

        let enviado = this.state.enviado;
        enviado=e;
        this.setState({enviado});
        alert(this.state.enviado);


    }
```

PERO ME SIGUE MOSTRANDO EL ESTADO ANTERIOR QUE ES VACIO

Answer (score 1):

Primero, has de saber que el estado no se va a actualizar hasta que la función termine de ejecutarse. En tu caso hasta que `ver` no termine de ejecutar código.

También has de tener en claro los siguiente:
* **La función `setState` es asíncrono, por ende, ya sea que uses un `alert` o un `console.log` tú estado no será el actual.**

Para evitar estos problemas has de usar la función `setState` de la siguiente manera:

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
   enviado: e
}));
```

Como consejo, no trates de sobre escribir la variables `state`. Quiero decir que no hagas esto:

```
let enviado = this.state.enviado;
enviado = e; // no hacer esto
```